# Update zabbix-agent mysql credentials

Tags: mysql, monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I want to monitor my mysql server with zabbix.

So i've created a mysql user called `zabbix`. The user got a secret password.

Now is my question where i can update the password in the zabbix config? I read some pages in the internet and found something like this: `mysql.status[zabbix,super-secret-password,Slow_queries]`

Where should I insert this?

Answer (score 0):

it's either in zabbix_agentd.conf.d or included in zabbix_agentd.conf
for my installation, zabbix configuration file is at /usr/local/zabbix/etc/

Comment: # find -name 'zabbix_agentd.conf' will show me this files: 
'./usr/share/zabbix-agent/zabbix_agentd.conf' and 
'./etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf' But in both there are only the 'GENERAL PARAMETERS' without mysql config